# page blashes while redirecting a form with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am learning to develop with codeigniter 3.1.8, for that I am confronted with a problem: I am confronted with a problem: I am redirected in a blank page and my errors do not display. please I would like to give you a hand

here is the function of the model for insertion

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class M_root extends CI_Model{



    function isertion_root(){
        $root=array(
            'nom_admin'=>'$user_name',
            'prenom_admin'=>'$user_prenom',
            'email_admin'=>'$user_email',
            'date_nais_admin'=>'$date_nais',
            'date_inscription_admin'=>'NOW(),false',
            'avatar_root'=>'$avatar_root',
            'password_root'=>'$pssword_root'

        );
        $this->db->insert('root', $root);
    }

    /**
     * @param $email
     * @param $password
     * @return bool
     */
    function login_root($email,$password){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('root');
        $this->db->where('email_admin',$email);
        $this->db->where('password_root',$password);

        if ($query=$this->db->get())
        {
            return $query->row_array();
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function email_check($email_admin){

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('root');
        $this->db->where('email_admin',$email_admin);
        $query=$this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }


}
```

here is the function of the controller for insertion

```
class Root extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('M_root');
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('session');

    }

    public function index()
       {
        $this->load->view("register.php");
        }

        //debut fonction d'enregistrement

        public function isertion_root(){
            if($this->input->post('registersubmit')){

            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/avatar-root/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if(!empty($_FILES['filefoto']['name']))
            {
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('filefoto'))
                {
                    $gbr = $this->upload->data();
                    //Compress Image
                    $config['image_library']='gd2';
                    $config['source_image']='./assets/avatar-root/'.$gbr['file_name'];
                    $config['create_thumb']= FALSE;
                    $config['maintain_ratio']= FALSE;
                    $config['quality']= '60%';
                    $config['new_image']= './assets/avatar-root/'.$gbr['file_name'];
                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();


                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nom_admin', 'nom administrateur', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[23]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('prenom_admin', 'prenom administrateur', 'trim|required|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_admin', 'Email administrateur', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_nais_admin', 'Date de naissance administateur', 'trim|required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('avatar_root', 'Avatar root', 'trim|required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_root', 'password root', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|xss_clean');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'confirm password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

                        $root = array(
                            'nom_admin' => strip_tags($this->input->post('nom_admin')),
                            'prenom_admin' => strip_tags($this->input->post('prenom_admin')),
                            'email_admin' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email_admin')),
                            'date_nais_admin' => strip_tags($this->input->post('date_nais_admin')),
                            'avatar_root' => strip_tags($this->input->post('avatar_root')),
                            'password_root' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'),PASSWORD_DEFAULT)


                        );
                        print_r($root);
                        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
                    {

                        $email_check=$this->M_root->email_check($root['email_admin']);

                       if($email_check){
                               $this->M_root->isertion_root($root);
                                $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Registered successfully.Now login to your account.');
                        redirect('root/login_view');

                                   }
                    }
                                     else{

                                    $this->load->view('register');


                                }

            }

        }
        }

    }
//fin fonction d'enregistrement
```

view

```
<span style="background-color:red;">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <div class="login-panel panel panel-success">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h3 class="panel-title">Creation d'un compte</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">

                  <p class="alert-danger"><?php
                  $error_msg=$this->session->flashdata('error_msg');
                  if($error_msg){
                    echo $error_msg;
                  }
                   ?></p>
                     <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
                      <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo base_url().'Root/isertion_root'?>">
                          <fieldset>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <?php echo form_error('nom_admin'); ?>
                                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Votre nom" name="nom_admin" value="<?php echo set_value('nom_admin'); ?>"type="text" autofocus>
                              </div>

                               <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Votre prenom" name="prenom_admin" type="text" autofocus>
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email_admin" type="email" autofocus>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="votre date de naissance" name="date_nais_admin" type="date" value="">
                              </div>

                               <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="mot de passe " name="password_root" type="password" value="">
                              </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="confirmez votre mot de passe" name="conf_password" type="password" value="">
                              </div>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="votre photo" name="avatar_root" type="file" value="">
                              </div>

                              <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Register" name="registersubmit" >

                          </fieldset>
                      </form>
                      <center><b>Already registered ?</b> <br></b><a href="<?php echo base_url('root/login_view'); ?>">Login here</a></center><!--for centered text-->
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>





</span>
```

Comment: its because you have ifs and no elses. somewhere along the lines an if isn't evaluating to true so your are getting a blank page because you have no else to handle the opposite condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once i faced with this same problem i rectified by using this please try this.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code contained many ifs and no elses. This mean if an if condition evaluates to false there is no reason for anything to be displayed.

This is a better way of doing it. If you keep everything all in one function and avoid redirects you can properly repopulate the input fields when an error occurs either from form validation or image uploading.

```
public function index() {
    if ($this->input->post('registersubmit')) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nom_admin', 'nom administrateur', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[23]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('prenom_admin', 'prenom administrateur', 'trim|required|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_admin', 'Email administrateur', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date_nais_admin', 'Date de naissance administateur', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('avatar_root', 'Avatar root', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_root', 'password root', 'trim|required|min_length[8]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'confirm password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $this->load->library('upload');
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/avatar-root/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = 100;
            $config['max_width'] = 1024;
            $config['max_height'] = 768;
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('filefoto')) {
                $gbr = $this->upload->data();
                //Compress Image
                $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = './assets/avatar-root/' . $gbr['file_name'];
                $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
                $config['quality'] = '60%';
                $config['new_image'] = './assets/avatar-root/' . $gbr['file_name'];
                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                $root = array(
                    'nom_admin' => strip_tags($this->input->post('nom_admin')),
                    'prenom_admin' => strip_tags($this->input->post('prenom_admin')),
                    'email_admin' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email_admin')),
                    'date_nais_admin' => strip_tags($this->input->post('date_nais_admin')),
                    'avatar_root' => strip_tags($this->input->post('avatar_root')),
                    'password_root' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
                );
                // i have a feeling you are checking if an email already exists here
                // you can use form validations is_unique function in the rules above and forgo this
                if ($this->M_root->email_check($root['email_admin'])) {
                    $this->M_root->isertion_root($root);
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Registered successfully.Now login to your account.');
                    redirect('root/login_view');
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'bad email');
                }
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', $this->upload->display_errors());
            }
        }
    }
    $this->load->view("register.php");
}
```

You just have to change your form action to be blank so it submits to the same page.

Also in each input `value` except passwords you should do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" size="50" />
```

This way the user won't lose their input when natural errors occur due to them entering wrong information or whatever.